# Convert array to object inclusive

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I convert a simple array like this: `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` to an object like this:

```
{ 'foo': {
    'bar': {
      'baz' : {}
    }
  }
}
```

It seems so simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempt. It should indeed be a simple recursive function or backward loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Array#reduceRight`:

```
function arrayToNestedObject(arr) {

    // Proceeding from the end of the array back towards the beginning...
    return arr.reduceRight(function(prev, cur) { 

        // Create a new object with a property named by the array element,
        // whose value is what we have got so far
        return Object.defineProperty({}, cur, {value: prev});

    }, {});
}
```

Test:

```
arrayToNestedObject(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
> {foo: {bar: {baz: {} } } }
```

Note that `Object.defineProperty({}, prop, {value: val})` is a convenient one-line shorthand for

```
var x = {};
x[prop] = val;
return x;
```

In ES6, using "computed properties", the above would simply be

```
arrayToNestedObject = (arr) => arr.reduceRight((prev, cur) => ({[cur]: prev}));
```

If one prefers a recursive solution, it is also better to proceed from the right, using `pop`:

```
function arrayToNestedObject(arr) {
    return (function _(arr, obj) {
      var val = arr.pop();
      return val ? _(arr, Object.defineProperty({}, val, {value: obj})) : obj;
    }(arr, {}));
}

arrayToNestedObject(['foo', 'bar'])
> { foo: { bar: { } } }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
function arrayToNestedObject(arr) {
    var obj = {},
        current = obj;

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var key = arr[i];
        current = current[key] = {};
    }

    return obj;
}

console.log(arrayToNestedObject(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']));
```

Comment: Got there 30 seconds before me. It should probably be noted that this won't work for nested arrays, fe `['foo','bar',['baz','buzz']]`. Although honestly, the original transformation is an unusual one in the  first place, and if you have nested arrays, should possibly be reconsidered.

Comment: @iabw: Where did you get the nested arrays from? OP doesn't mention them.

Comment: The meaning of nested arrays in other than terminal position is unclear. If `['foo', 'bar', ['baz', 'buzz'], 'garb']`, then where does `garb` go?